# Parsing JSON array with NewtonSoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My JSON looks like this:

```
[[["Text 1.A","Text 1.B",null,null,3],["Text 2.A","Text 2.B",null,null,1],["Text 3.A","Text 3.B",null,null,3],["Text 4.A","Text 4.B",null,null,3]],null,"en"]
```

and I need to get all the A texts into one string. There can be more than 4 values in the array.

I've tried searching online but for some reason I can't find a solution, or I don't understand the solution. I'm completely new to JSON so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your json data isn't valid

Comment: Explain further what you mean by "A texts into one string".What is your expected output for your json in your question?

Comment: First correct your json string. You can go here to validate your json string : [link](https://jsonlint.com)

Comment: @gerryc.inc Expected result is Text 1.A + Text 2.A + ... + Text n.A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's not correct JSON. I hope double quote is just a typo.

Second, your JSON looks extremely shapeless. It's an array of anything, first element is also an array of arrays with anything. That kind of structures have to be at some point parsed manually.

If I understand you correctly, you need those texts with `.A`. This should do the job:

```
string json =
    "[[[\"Text 1.A\",\"Text 1.B\",null,null,3],[\"Text 2.A\",\"Text 2.B\",null,null,1],[\"Text 3.A\",\"Text 3.B\",null,null,3],[\"Text 4.A\",\"Text 4.B\",null,null,3]],null,\"en\"]";

var tokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken[]>(json);
var subArray = tokens[0].ToObject<JToken[]>();
var aTexts = subArray.Select(a =>
{
    var arr = a.ToObject<object[]>();
    return (string)arr[0];
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. And the JSON comes from Google Translate:
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=fi&dt=t&q=One.+Two.+Three.+Four.+Five.

The double quote was a typo.